# Missing User Certificates Folder

Tags: windows-10, certificate

I'm encountering a strange issue on a couple of machines under my control. They appear to be missing a critical folder in the User Certificates manager.

[image]

This is how the Personal folder should look in the User Certificate manager. However, the affected machines are missing that "certificates" folder under Personal. I cannot figure out how to restore this folder, and without it, the affected machines cannot request New Certificates from the Active Directory Enrollment Policy.

How can I restore the "certificates" folder under the Personal parent?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever backed up the certificates under the personal? If there is, I suggest you can refer to [this article](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/November2017/Subsystems/Server/Content/QlikView-Server/QVSRM_CertificateBackupRestore.htm) to restore it.

If not, I hope the following methods may help you, specific information can be viewed in this article: [How to Restore a Deleted Certificate](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-restore-a-deleted-certificate)

> 1. Open Internet Explorer and click \"**Tools**\" from the main panel. Scroll down and click \"**Internet Options**.\"
> 2. Click the \"**Content**\" tab on the options window, then click \"**Certificates**.\" Click the \"**Import**\" button and follow the
>      certificate import wizard to load a deleted certificate. Certificates
>      are stored in Certificate stores.
> 3. Enter the password for the certificate file when you are prompted to, then check both the \"**Enable strong private key protection**\"
>      and \"**Mark the private key as exportable**\" boxes.
> 4. Click the \"**High**\" security option when prompted to in the private exchange key window. Click '**Next**.\"
> 5. Choose \"**Create a password for this item**\" and set your password. Enter the password you just assigned. Click \"**OK**\" to
>      complete the importation of a deleted certificate.